# What is the relationship, if any, between maximal domains of $f$ and $f'(x)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure, domain-theory

(Edited question after some Calculus review)

Let $D$ be the maximal domain of function $f$. Let $D^d$ be the largest subset of $D$ where $f'(x)$ is defined.

1. Maximal domain of $f(x) = \ln(x)$ is $D_1 = (0, \infty)$

Its derivative $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is defined on $D_1$

2. Maximal domain of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is $D_2 = [0, \infty)$

While $f' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is not defined on $D_2$, it is defined on $D_2^d := (0, \infty)$

$D_2$ and $D_2^d$ differ only by one value.

3. Maximal domain of $f(x) = |x|$ is $D_3 = \mathbb R$

While $f' = \frac{|x|}{x}$ is not defined on $D_3$, it is defined on $D_3^d := \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$

$D_3$ and $D_3^d$ differ only by one value.

4. Maximal domain of $f(x) =  \lfloor x \rfloor$ is $D_4 = \mathbb R$

While $f'$ is not defined on $D_4$, it is defined on $D_4^d := \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z$

$D_4$ and $D_4^d$ differ only by countably many values.

It seems that $D$ and $D^d$ differ by only a set of Lebesgue measure zero.

However, the Weierstrass function disproves that conjecture.

So what kind of conditions of $f$ are sufficient or necessary to have such a relationship between $D$ and $D^d$?

Comment: It's not at all clear what the edit means. Isn't the question about functions that (like $x \mapsto x^{1 / 2}$) are *not* differentiable at every point of their domain, and about the sets on which they fail to be differentiable?

Comment: @Travis Hmmm...perhaps we might have to put this on hold. I was just wondering if a function $f$ that is differentiable everywhere will have the same domain as its derivative $f'$. Oh shoot, so $\sqrt{x}$ technically doesn't have a derivative? Hmm...might have to edit. I'm going to VTC my question then

Comment: I wouldn't say that $\sqrt{x}$ "doesn't have a derivative", it's just that $\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x}$ doesn't have the same domain as $\sqrt{x}$ itself. But if this isn't the distinction you're trying to draw, I don't understand the original question either.

Comment: Instead of V-ing TC, you can also delete your own question if you'd rather.

Comment: @Travis Tried. Can't. Delete your answer please? :P

Comment: Oh, right, I'd forgotten. You'd have to contact mvw to do the same, so it's probably just sensible to let the question sit and maybe eventually close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without more hypotheses, anyway: The [Weierstrass function(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) are the standard example of a function that is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere: Weierstrass' original family of examples were given by
$$f(x) := \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a^n \cos (b^n \pi x),$$
where $0 < a < 1$ and $b$ a positive odd integer such that $ab > 1 + \frac{3 \pi}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: This does not meet the assumption of having a derivative then?

Comment: Yes; in the language of the question, $\operatorname{dom}(f')$ is the empty set. In particular the Lebesgue measures of $f$ and $f'$ are different. (In fact, one is infinite, and one is zero.)

Comment: nvm just VTC my question please. thank you anyway.

Comment: Edited question!

Comment: Never mind I'll just ask more questions.